# can i decrypt the data using SHA 5 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the data using SHA 5 in mysql. I am able to encrypt the data but unable to decrypt it. How can I achieve the decrption of SHA5 encrypted data in mysql.

Comment: MySQL has native MD5() and SHA1() functions. Perhaps you are confusing the two (or maybe using the Java SHA5)?  In either case though, the SHAn are _hashing algorithms_ not encryption algorithms, meaning they are one-way only. They _cannot_ be decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly want to do ? As Michael says, you will not be able to reverse a hash. We use hash when we want hide the real information and never decrypt it. If you want to decrypt it, then use an inversible function.

Answer (score -1):

Hash algorithms (SHA = secure hash algorithm) are one way. You can use then to verify information such as a password by checking that the password entered, when SHA'd, equals the encrypted version on record. You can't decrypt with it though.

Comment: I want to store the user information in encrypted format. How can I do this in MYSQL? I want to use 512 bit hash.